# Can I post JSON format in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a JSON file and I want to send it to the RequestHandler. The error response is the following:
`java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: What you are calling a "JSON file" in your question is obviously stored as a `LinkedHashMap` in your application's memory according to the error message. So you need to lookup how to convert a `HashMap` to a JSON String.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to send a LinkedHashMap, as the error and @Mark B says, to the RequestHandler. Instead, "stringify" it into a JSON string first.
I recommend one of two libraries for this.

**Google's GSON library**

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(jsonData, LinkedHashMap.class);
```

**Java's JSON library**

```
String jsonString = new JSONObject(jsonData).toString()
```

Then, send this string to the RequestHandler. Hope this helps.